# Alternative to forwardRef in newer Angular versions?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I'm trying to update an old project to the latest version of Angular and I discovered that this line

```js
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => MapComponent)) private map: MapComponent) {}
```

causes the app to be stuck on `Loading...`.

TSLint also gives me the following message:

> Avoid using forwardRef() in class (no-forward-ref).

How can I rewrite this constructor?

Comment: Can't you just skip it? (if you've added to as a provider) `constructor(private map: MapComponent) {`

Comment: @FredrikLundin I can do that? Would I need to change code elsewhere if I skip it?

Comment: Try it - it should work without the `forwardRef`. If it does - let med know and I'll add it as an answer

Comment: @FredrikLundin It does not solve the problem. It seems that something is changing when I remove `forwardRef`

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit more? What is `MapComponent`, how is it declared and how is it being used?

Comment: @FredrikLundin The code is not mine and is badly written, I will accept Dean's answer and try to find a solution based on that information.

Comment: where is your `MapComponent` defined and what class does the constructor you're showing refers to? Read [What is `forwardRef` in Angular and why we need it](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/what-is-forwardref-in-angular-and-why-we-need-it-6ecefb417d48) to understand why we need `forwardRef`. Interestingly that although cli warns about the usage, it's used inside Angular sources as the article I referenced shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a circular dependency in your injection setup. `forwardRef` is there to resolve some of these types of issues as classes aren't hoisted and this can cause some type instance resolution errors. You are getting the `tslint` error because the style guide suggests that you restructure your app to not have dependency resolution issues rather than rely on `forwardRef`.

If someone has added `forwardRef` earlier in your code, then it is probably for a reason - so removing it will possibly give you a different error.
I would try to hoist the MapComponent in the code and then remove the forwardRef declaration - as I suspect some other issue is at the root of a stalled bootstrap in this instance